# Bode plot of an exponential function

Tags: control-theory

Could anyone please explain how to sketch the bode plot for an open loop transfer function involving an exponential term ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An exponential term, representing a delay, has a gain of 0dB and phase proportional to frequency.